# how to enable a disabled button if only one star button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter and I have a form where a user can rate a product. My code is below shown. I need to make  submit button disable at the beginning and when ever a user selects  a star button only that submit button needs to be enabled . How can i achieve that? Please anyone guide me. because i don't understand the javascript code as i pasted from the internet.Can anyone help me please?

businessRateView.php

```
 <?php $Vehicleid=$details['id']; ?>
                            <form action="<?php echo 'http://localhost/ci/businessRateCtrl/insertIntoBusinessReview/'.$Vehicleid?> " method="POST">

                            <h2>Rate Ad</h2>
                            <p>All field marked with * are required</p>
                            <div style="color:red">
                        <?php
                            $CI =& get_instance();
                            $CI->load->library('form_validation');
                            echo validation_errors();
                        ?>
                        </div>

                             <div class="spacer-20"></div>
                            <h4>Your rating*</h4>


                            <h1><div class="rating" style="width:200px;float:left;padding-left:1px">
                                <span class="rate-star" data-rate="Excellent">&bigstar;</span> 
                                <span class="rate-star" data-rate="Good" >&bigstar;</span> 
                                <span class="rate-star" data-rate="Okay" >&bigstar;</span>
                                <span class="rate-star" data-rate="Unsatisfied" >&bigstar;</span>
                                <span class="rate-star" data-rate="Terrible" >&bigstar;</span>
                                </div>
                            </h1>

                            <div style="float:right;padding-right:450px">
                            <h3><label id="rateText" name="lblrating"></label></h3>
                            </div>


                            <div class="spacer-20"></div>



                             <h4>Write your review</h4>
                              <div class="spacer-20"></div>
                            <label class="col-md-4"> Title </label> 
                            <input type="text" name="reviewTitle" placeholder="Title your review" class="form-control">     

                            <div class="spacer-20"></div>

                            <label class="col-md-4">Your review </label>       
                            <textarea rows="10" cols="103" name="review" placeholder="Write your review" class="form-control"></textarea>
                            <div class="spacer-20"></div>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href=<?php echo 'http://localhost/ci/adpreview_ctrl/getad_preview/'.$Vehicleid?>  onclick="return cancelConfirm();">Cancel</a>

                            <input type="submit" name="submitreview" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="SUBMIT">

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.onload = function() {
                    var starList = document.getElementsByClassName('rate-star');  
                    var numOfStars = starList.length;

                        for(var i = 0; i < numOfStars; i++) {
                            starList[i].addEventListener('click', starClickHandler, false);
                        }
                    }

                        function starClickHandler(event) {
                            var star = event.currentTarget;

                            setActive(star, false);
                            setActive(star, true);
                            document.getElementById('rateText').textContent = star.getAttribute('data-rate');
                        }

                        function setActive(element, isActive) {
                            if(isActive) {
                            element.classList.add('active');
                            element.nextElementSibling && setActive(element.nextElementSibling, isActive);
                            }
                            else {
                            element.classList.remove('active');
                            element.previousElementSibling && setActive(element.previousElementSibling, isActive);
                            }
                            }



                        function cancelConfirm(){
                            return confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel and leave this page?");
                        }

            </script>

            <style type="text/css">
                        #rateText{

                    text-align:right;

                        }
                        .rating {
                            unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
                            direction: rtl ;
                                }


                                .rating > .rate-star.active,
                                .rating > .rate-star:hover,
                                .rating > .rate-star:hover ~ .rate-star {
                                     color: #FFFF00;
                                    cursor: default;
                                    }
            </style>
```

businessRateCtrl.php

```
 public function loadReviewPage($vehicleid){


    $data=array();
    $data['details']['id']=$vehicleid;

    $this->load->view('pages/templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/businessRateView',$data);
        $this->load->view('pages/templates/footer');



}

public function insertIntoBusinessReview($Vehicleid){

      $data=array();
    $data['details']['id']=$Vehicleid;

 $this->form_validation->set_rules
        (
            'lblrating',
            'lblrating', 
            'required',
            array
            (
                'required'      => 'You have not provided Rating',

            )
        );


          if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
          $this->load->view('pages/templates/header');
            $this->load->view('pages/businessRateView',$data);
            $this->load->view('pages/templates/footer');

        }

else{
          $this->main_model->insertIntoBusinessReview($Vehicleid);
      //$_SESSION['ads']=$_SESSION['ads']+1;
      $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Thank you! We will post your review soon');
      redirect("<?php echo 'http://localhost/ci/adpreview_ctrl/getad_preview/'.'$Vehicleid' ?>");

    }
```

}

mainmodel.php

public function insertIntoBusinessReview($Vehicleid){

```
    $rating = $_POST['lblrating'];

    if(($_POST['reviewTitle'])!==null || ($_POST['review'])!==null)
    {
    $title=$_POST['reviewTitle'];
    $review=$_POST['review'];

    $data=array('Vehicleid'=>$Vehicleid,'rating'=>$rating,'title'=>$title,'review'=> $review,'reviewPoster'=>$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['email']);
    $this->db->insert('businessreviews',$data);
    }

    $data=array('Vehicleid'=>$Vehicleid,'rating'=>$rating,'reviewPoster'=>$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['email']);
    $this->db->insert('businessreviews',$data);


}
```

Here

```
function starClickHandler(event) {
                            var star = event.currentTarget;

                            setActive(star, false);
                            setActive(star, true);
                            document.getElementById('rateText').textContent = star.getAttribute('data-rate');
```

from above code it set label "rateText" into "Excellent","Good" or whatever the text belongs to the button which is clicked.

So if i need to take the text "Excellent","Good" etc. and insert it into the db how can i do that? Can you please kind enough to help me?

Comment: So...you want us to walk you through code, explaining it to you? That isn't really what this site is for.

Comment: In your function: `function setActive(element, isActive)` put the code to make the submit button active... You know how to set the button "inactive" and "active" or is that what you need help with?

Comment: @kirkpatt- no no sorry if i say something irrelevant , I just want to know how to trigger that button is clicked . and how to take the text which is  appearing where "lblrating" label is , to insert into the db.

Comment: for the button click you could use the [onclick](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) method and call a function on it... to read the "field":  [`document.getElementById("lblrating").innerHTML`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) or on server side, which I guess is more aprpiate, using `$_POST["lblrating"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [Remove attribute](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".rating .rate-star").click(function(){
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $( ".rate-star:lt("+($(this).index()+1)+")" ).addClass("active");
        $("#rateText").html($(this).data("rate"));
        $("#submitreview").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
```

[Sample of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/3jmd468d/)

Comment: Can you please tell me where should i paste this code

Comment: I think this is jQuery, am i right. i'm a completely a beginner to jQuery. That's why i asked as where to put this code as i cannot understand it clearly. anyhow i was able to solved the problem .Thank you for your help :-) :-)

Comment: ok add jquery library to your project and just give that script